# If+subject+would

Tags: grammar

Last night as I watched a video on Youtube I heard a sentence which has gotten me into confusion.

The person on that video said:

> If we would put the new tax bill aside, we would be able to solve the budget issue.

I know how in English 2nd conditional works and I suppose the sentence above is also a 2nd conditional sentence. Also, I know one can use "would" in the if-clause to make the statement/demand/suggestion more polite.

However, the first sentence does not have a sense of politeness and I quite frequently hear most native speakers of AE use this kind of 2nd conditional structure.

What I am wondering is that if I were to use this twice-would structure in an informal environment, would that be considered acceptable ? If I produced such a structure in an email to my colleague, would he/she think that I make a huge mistake or would the meaning just come across and my colleague would not even notice I made a mistake ?

Comment: I don't see any issue with this sentence as a native AmE speaker, and if I heard it I wouldn't think twice about it.

Comment: Other options include "If we put...", "If we were to put ...", "If we do put ..."

Comment: When you have a *would* in the *if* clause in standard English, you should read it as *if we were willing to put the new tax bill aside*. So your sentence is perfectly fine. On the other hand, sentences like *if it would rain, the ducks would be happy* are generally considered unacceptable (except in certain dialects of American English).

Comment: Holding the spoken word to the strictness of the written word is gonna hurt. A lot. Using *would* is overkill, and also okay.

Comment: The grammar of conditionals is in the midst of change in English usage.  The 'rules' I was taught in school over 50 years ago less and less reflect what people actually say or write.  In the so-called 'second conditional' (what used to be called 'future remote/unlikely/impossible'), You used either "if I were to put..." or just "if I put".The grammar of conditionals is in the midst of change in English usage.  The 'rules' I was taught in school over 50 years ago less and less reflect what people actually say or write.  [continued]

Comment: In the so-called 'second conditional' (what used to be called 'future remote/unlikely/impossible'), You used either "if I were to put..." or just "if I put".  You can make it unmistakeable by using the alternative "if I were to put" as has already been said in another comment.    I cannot answer for American English, but to me, a Brit, "If I would put", in this context, looks odd.

Comment: @PeterShor is correct; this is the *would* that means [*to be willing*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/would) (see 8 at Macmillan).

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, Peter Shor wrote:

> When you have a *would* in the *if* clause in standard English, you should read it as *if we were willing to put the new tax bill aside*. So your sentence is perfectly fine. On the other hand, sentences like *if it would rain, the ducks would be happy* are generally considered unacceptable (except in certain dialects of American English).